# How to display Download Progress in a Notification in Ionic Hybrid App?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I want to display Download Progress in a Notification Bar for my Ionic Hybrid App.like [native app](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/display-progress.html). I am using [cordova file transfer](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileTransfer/) plugin for download files.

Is this possible for Ionic App? How can i do that?

Like this:

[image]

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: Not yet, better ask ionic community if they provide any solution.

Comment: Looking for answer to this same question. Would html provided to `text` property of `cordova-plugin-background-mode`'s `configure` method work?

Answer (score 0):

This following solution is in Ionic-Angular -
It shows how to download data into dataDirectory using file-transfer and show download progress notification.

**data-directory-manager.service.ts :**

```
import { FileTransfer, FileTransferObject } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer/ngx';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';
import { NotificationService } from './notification.service';

@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataDirectoryManagerService {
    constructor(
        private file:File, 
        private transfer:FileTransfer,
        private notificationService :NotificationService
        ){}

    fileTransferProgressBar()
    {
        this.fileTransfer.onProgress((progressEvent) => {
        var perc = Math.floor(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total * 100);
        this.notificationService.updateNotificationProgress(1,perc,"downloaded "+ perc + " %");
        console.log(" Downloaded File progress = "+ perc + " %");
        if(perc==100)
        {
            //remove notification after download completed
            this.notificationService.cancelNotification(1);
        }
        });
    }

   downloader(url, fileName)
   {
    this.notificationService.sendNotification(1,"downloading "+ fileName, "some text", 0);
    this.fileTransfer.download(url, this.file.dataDirectory + fileName).then((entry) => {
        console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
        console.log("Completed download for => " + fileName);
      }, (error) => {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
      });
   }
}
```

My notification service :
**notification.service.ts**

```
import { LocalNotifications} from '@ionic-native/local-notifications/ngx';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NotificationService {

  constructor(private localNotifications:LocalNotifications) { }

  async sendNotification(id, title, text, value) {
    await this.localNotifications.schedule({
      id: id,
      title: title,
      text: text,
      progressBar: { 
        value: value,
      },
      sticky: true,
    });
   
  }

  async updateNotificationProgress(id:number, progressValue:number, text:string)
  {
    await this.localNotifications.update({
      id:id,
      progressBar:{value:progressValue},
      text:text
    });
  }

  async cancelNotification(id:number)
  {
    await this.localNotifications.cancel(id);
  }
}
```

Refer the following links for detailed explanation :

- https://enappd.com/blog/local-notifications-in-ionic-4/69/
- https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications
- https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/local-notifications/

Answer (score -1):

Use [cordovaToast](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/toast/)  plugin  for this feature.Here is the example for showing pdf download progress

**html**

```
<ion-view >
    <div class="bar bar-subheader bar-positive" style="padding:0px;height: 8px;" >
        <progress id="progressbar" max="100" value="{{ downloadProgress }}" class="progress"> </progress>
    </div>
    <ion-content>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**css**

```
.progress {
    margin: 0 px;
    height: 8 px;
    background - color: #F1292B!important;
    border - radius: 2 px;
    box - shadow: 0 2 px 5 px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset;
}
```

**js**

```
if (window.cordova) {
    var url = '{{base_url}}/pdf_download/' + id;
    // Android
    var targetPath = 'file:///storage/sdcard0/' + 'fpl_' + id + '.pdf';
    var trustHosts = true;
    var options = {};
    $cordovaFileTransfer.download(url, targetPath, options, trustHosts)
        .then(function(result) {
            $cordovaToast
                .show('File downloaded successfully..', 'short', 'center')
                .then(function() {
                    // success
                }, function() {
                    // error
                });

            console.log(result);
        }, function() {
            var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: 'No internet access',
                buttons: [{
                    text: 'OK',
                    type: 'button-assertive'
                }]
            });
            alertPopup.then(function() {});

        }, function(progress) {
            var dnldpgs = progress.loaded.toString().substring(0, 2);
            $scope.downloadProgress = parseInt(dnldpgs);
        });
}
```

If you have any doubt.Please let me know.Thanks.

Comment: i tried your solution but it works different way, it just show a short message at screen like popup. i need it work like image in my question(updated). how to do that ?

Comment: Is there a way we can show it the notification, bar other than inside the app??? Just like native app notification comes